# i am looking for a proper JPQL query for the below tables so that it can work in java code it should not to be a native query

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

below is the table schema for which i am not able to make proper JPQL query

```
  Mobile table     | hardware table       |  releases table
  --------------------------------------------------------------
  id pk            |   id  pk            | id  pk
  name varchar         size  varchar       launchdate varchar
  hardware_id fk   |   pdname varchar    | tally  varchar
  releases_id fk   |                     | 

 i have tried all below query's in my code but it all gives error for:
  //String qry="Select m.name,h.size,h.pdname from com.example.users.Mobile m, 
   com.example.users.entities.Hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id ";


    //String qry="Select m from Mobile m inner join fetch m.hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id";

    //String qry = "SELECT m FROM Mobile m JOIN m.hardware_id h WHERE m.hardware_id = h.id";

    String qry="select m.name from mobile m,hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id";


   System.out.println("in entity manager Query is "+ qry);

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(qry);

    return query.getResultList();
```

Error:   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: mobile is not mapped

```
 This is what i have in Mobile Entity

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name ="hardware_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Hardware hardware;

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="releases_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Releases releases;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you are specifying in `@JoinColumn` is database column not your entity attribute name.
Issue is you are mixing your attribute and column names.

**Query:**

`"SELECT m FROM Mobile m JOIN Hardware h ON m.hardware.id = h.id"`

Comment: Will you please elaborate i havnt get yet

Comment: hardware.id i should use i was using hardware_id which was giving me error..Appreciate your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a property like this in the `Mobile` entity?

```
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hardware_id")
    private Hardware hardware;
```

Comment: this is what i have in mobile entity:@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name ="hardware_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Hardware hardware;
 
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="releases_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
 private Releases releases;

Comment: i have updated same in the post..you can look there

Comment: done the mention changes still same error: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception isorg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: mobile is not mapped [select m.brand, m.phone from mobile m,hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id AND sim = 'Nano']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: mobile is not mapped [select m.brand, m.phone from mobile m,hardware h where m.hardware_id=h.id AND sim = 'Nano']]